# Declaring array causing error

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I am unable to **execute** the below code in codeblock ide but if I declare the array globally then I can **execute** it.
 What are the limits on array size when declared globally and when declared locally ? **What is the thumb rule for declaring array size in competitive programming contest like spoj, codechef etc?**
Also if the error is due to codeblock ide. Then how can I correct it ?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int arr[999999];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  What's your compilation error?  Have you tried dynamically allocating the array?

Comment: compiler version + compilation mode

Comment: Add operating system too, it will not cause error in new Linux but problematic in Windows and Dos.

Comment: There shouldn't be any error. Please say your compiler and compile error. I tested it and there was no error.

Comment: Global variables are allocate in their own space, whereas if you declare this array locally it will simply be too big to fit on the stack

Comment: Sry all, please see the edit.its compiling but not executing

Comment: Exactly what happens when you try to execute it? If there's an error message, what is it?

Answer (score 7):

The reason this is disallowed is because it would add a total of 999999*sizeof(int) bytes (7.6MiB in a typical 64-bit environment) to the stack frame of main(), which is a very large amount of memory for a single stack frame.

The maximum size of a stack frame depends on your implementation and environment settings.

If you do need this memory, you should either locate it statically (using a static variable) or dynamically, depending on whether you need to have multiple calls of main() inside your program. If you settle for dynamic memory, consider using a vector instead and using `std::vector<int> arr(999999);` in order to declare a vector with the initial size set to 999999.

Answer (score 5):

Without the exact error (can you provide this?) it's hard to say exactly what's happen but more likely than not you are getting a stack overflow. The specific size of the stack is iplementation defined, mosst platform provide a mean of enlarging it.

The easiest and most correct solution to this problem is to use a managed standard container to hold the array like a `std::vector`, this will allocate onto the freestore and manage the memory for you as well as provide a consistant interface.

```
#include <vector>
int main() {
     std::vector<int> arr (999999);
     return 0;
}
```

As a general rule, prefer containers to raw arrays there is very little if any overhead.

### Reference

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, variables declared in global scope are "allocated" in the .data or .bss section of a ELF executable file. Variables, including vectors, declared inside a method/function are allocated dynamically from the stack when the method/function is executing. The size of the stack is dependent of operating system.

So, in summary this error is most likely due to stack overflow =D

In a programming contest (spoj, topcoder, icpc, codejam, etc.) is a good idea to declare you vector dynamically. Be it using vector, malloc or new. This guarantee that you use only the needed amount of memory.